# Is there a way to debug an android application on the phone without the USB connection?

Tags: android, eclipse

Is there a way to install an application I'm in the middle of development on to my phone without going through all the steps of signing it, releasing it etc.? (Without the phone being connected by USB)

I'm still very much mid-development, but I need to demonstrate the progress I've made so far to other members of my team away from access to my development environment, so I need to install it on my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your project bin folder there is an apk file. If you copy that file to a device you can then install the app from it.

When I am in your situation I throw my apk into dropbox and send out links for people to download it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try adb wireless http://www.helloandroid.com/content/connect-your-android-phone-adb-wireless

But i don't really see why you cannot export and install an unsigned app?

Answer (score 0):

At&t (and possibly other carriers) set up the firmware to prohibit sideloading, so you need USB connection if that is your carrier.  Otherwise, just put the apk on a web site and enable installation from unapproved sources.

Comment: They have eased up on this I believe all modern phones on US carriers allow sideloading.

Answer (score 0):

See for the purpose of debugging you can use the adb-wireless which provides the same functionality as the use of a USB.

Also for installing it on the phone directly you can try this and see if this helps.

1. Go to Settings -> Applications
2. Select the Unknown sources option. This allows you to install apps on your phone even if the app is not released into the Android Market.
3. If you are using Eclipse or any other IDE just click on the project and run as android application. The app shall get installed directly.  ( Installation shall not depend upon whether you are using adb-wireless or a USB)