# Android App installation on phone for testing : Suggestions

Tags: android, android-install-apk

I am trying my hands on the android app development and need your suggestions to mitigate my current situation.

My organization has disabled USB for the desktop and I wouldn't be able to connect my phone through USB to test my application as I code.

- I have installed genymotion but since it is behind proxy, in all the ways I could configure it, it gives proxy authentication error.
- The avd is comparitively slower and the app which am trying needs internet connectivity at every step. I have tried these too and my impression is that we can make
  the avd work for connecting to internet through its webbrowser but it cannot connect to internet within the apps. I might be wrong here. Please let me know if it is not the case.

Is there any other way where we can install the app in the phone as and when we code to test it..?
One option can be to export an apk file everytime and install them on the phone by sending this apk through a mail. But this will be a cumbersome activity if we have to test as and when we code.

Any suggestions on this..?

PS: I do not want to hack the desktop to enable the USB.Also using an external laptop with USB enabled is out of option in my case.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is using AirDroïd. You just need to install it on your test device, and you can manage it with a webapp :

your.static.ip.xx:8888

You can install your app with that way, it's really easy, you don't need any account in a local network.

For testing... no idea without usb, or without the emulator. Maybe you can log everything in a text file & get it (with airdroid for example).

**EDIT**

I think if you create an account you can use it external of you network.
http://web.airdroid.com/
Just create an account, & log on web & on the app, you could use it on the external way.

Comment: Thanks Sidd. I think this is the best solution I have for the time being. I tried in my home network and it is fabulous.. One question: My organization has a wireless network and when I connect airdoid to it it gives an IP address..but my desktop is not in the same network as the device is in(it is wired).. Is there any solution to overcome this..?

Comment: I think if you create an account you can use it external of you network. http://web.airdroid.com/ Just create an account, & log on web & on the app, you could use it on the external way.

Comment: Yep creating an account does help as we can access from the browser..Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why are you even bothering to use the desktop PC when your organization has made it unsuitable for development.

It will be hard work, but you could do all your development on the Android device itself, using [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui)

(Actually AIDE is pretty practical as a IDE if you have a large screen tablet, and pair it with a full size bluetooth keyboard).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It is for learning purpose and hence they would not support by providing a laptop. Having said that, this is a good alternative too but I do not have a bluetooth keyboard/tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Quote: "Inside your project bin folder there is an apk file. If you copy that file to a device you can then install the app from it.

When I am in your situation I throw my apk into dropbox and send out links for people to download it."
from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9396417/3604360)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. It was an added info for me which I wasn't aware of till now.. I will keep this as the last option..

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that if your company has disabled USB they still allow Bluetooth, but because you did not state it specifically:
If you can use Bluetooth, the best way would be to use it for running and debugging your App.
There are some Tutorials on the web.

For Example: http://zcourts.com/2013/07/19/android-debugging-over-bluetooth-without-root/